# AATL document signing certificate in Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, adobe, digital-signature, azure-keyvault

This question was already asked before, e.g. [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/bcc42f87-0c83-4f75-b47e-629bff228796/document-signing-certificates-in-azure-key-vault?forum=AzureKeyVault) and [here](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/signing-a-pdf-file-using-azure-key-vault/#comment-3932224339), but the answers are rather old and I wonder if something has changed in the meantime.

I would like to sign pdf documents from azure functions with an adobe trusted certificate. But obviously these AATL document signing certicates are only available as usb tokens/hsm and cannot be used from Azure Key Vault.

I guess signing pdfs from within Azure is quite a common task. Am I missing something? Is there an inexpensive alternative (for a small company)?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm now using a regular, untrusted certificate and asked my users to trust it by importing a fdf file (as described here: https://www.computertutoring.co.uk/import-digital-signatures-acrobat.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this approach for a year. You need CA that can issue a digital signing certificate as PFX file or issue with CSR created from Azure Key Vault.

Now some CA can issue a digital signing certificate with AATL for this case.